# Сервлет с кучей методов, имена которых соответствуют url

Tags: servlet, jsp, java

Допустим, такая ситуация:

1. Имеем сервлет CommentServlet
2. Имеем следующие url, которые этот сервлет обрабатывает в методе doGet

   localhost/comment?delete=true&id=123  
   localhost/comment?remove=true&id=124  
   localhost/comment?vote=true&id=19

и т.д.

Как можно сделать так, чтобы можно было вызывать сервлет по адресу:

```
localhost/comment/delete?id=123
localhost/comment/vote?id=19
```

и в этом сервлете были соответствующие методы, например:

```
protected void doGet(... request, ... response) {...}
protected void delete(... request, ... response) {...}
protected void vote(... request, ... response) {...}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В чистом виде красиво это сделать не получится. Можно сделать через рефлекшны, но это кривизна. Вся проблема в том, что вы хотите получить "плохую" архитектуру.

Нет смысла объединять обработку этих методов в одно сервлет. Сделайте несколько сервлетов и запапьте их на эти URL'ы. Если у них есть общий код, то вынесите его из сервлета, либо сделайте базовый класс для этих сервлетов и общую часть занесите в базовый абстрактный класс.

Comment: Сделал с помощью рефлекшн. Получилось вполне неплохо. Базовый класс имеет метод doGet, а текущий класс имеет только имена методов vote, delete, add и т.д. Спс.

Comment: Но зачем так странно? Я так и не понял.

Comment: Чтобы отделить логику по методам. код преобразился))

Comment: Так почему нельзя разделить методы по разным классам вообще? Вы ведь пишете паттерны в web.xml.. вот и замапьте правильно там на разные реализации..

Comment: Зачем плодить кучу сервлетов если можно всё в одном?) /comment/* - так замаппил. Если обратиться по /comment/delete?id=1 - в базовом классе извлекаю "/delete" из url и вызываю метод delete(...req, ...res) у наследника; Очень неплохо. Видимо я ещё не столкнулся с подводными камнями...

Comment: Можно задать аналогичный вопрос: зачем кидать совершенно разные методы в кучу? :) Впрочем, если они очень очень малы, то, возможно, вы правы..

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой принцип в проектировании: (The Single Responsibility Principle) "Если на вопрос -А что умеет этот класс?- в ответе встречается "И", или "ИЛИ", (например, мой класс умеет удалять объекты И создавать...) - это первый признак того, что нужно его разделять на два отдельных". Это конечно, утопия, но в рамках здравого смысла об этом надо помнить и применять повсеместно.

Как сказал классик - "код, понятный машине могут написать многие. Высший пилотаж - писать код, понятный человеку."(с)